# Error while scripting ArcGIS in VB.NET "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040202"

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, error, vb.net, 3d-analyst

I am getting this Run time Error while coding ArcGIS in VB.NET script to calculate distance between two 3-D objects.

> “Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040202”

I tried to understand the problem but failed. Please help me to debug. I am trying to add a screen shot but it looks like i need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Actually my work is to create a Rectangular plane with 3D vertices below earth's surface and to find distance to the plane from all the points of a Grid created on earth's surface. All this work is to be done in ArcGIS. So I created a Geodatabase in Geographic Coordinate System WGS-1984. Then I created a grid file and added envelope, lats and longs etc. Then I created two shape files a point and a polygon in GCS and projected them to UTM system. Then I used an interface called I3DProximity to find the distance. Then it gave the error.

So here's my code. First I created Geodatabase here and assigned Geographic coodrinate system: Though I have given the whole code, I guess the error is somewhere in the last 2 parts, like in spatial referencing and using IProximity3D interface.

```vb
        Dim wksp As IWorkspace
        wksp = CreateFileGDB(mainPath, GDBName)
        Dim fWS As IFeatureWorkspace
        fWS = CType(wksp, IFeatureWorkspace)

        Dim pSpatialReferenceEnvironment As SpatialReferenceEnvironment
        pSpatialReferenceEnvironment = New SpatialReferenceEnvironment
        Dim pGeographicCoordinateSystem As IGeographicCoordinateSystem
        pGeographicCoordinateSystem = pSpatialReferenceEnvironment.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984)

        Dim pfeatclass As IFeatureClass
        pfeatclass = CreateFeatureClassWithFields(mainName, fWS)

        'Adding Fields to the GDB file
        newfields()

        'polygons
        Dim pworkedit As IWorkspaceEdit = CType(wksp, IWorkspaceEdit)
        Dim pfeaturebuffer As IFeatureBuffer

        pworkedit.StartEditing(True)
        pworkedit.StartEditOperation()
        pfeaturebuffer = pfeatclass.CreateFeatureBuffer

        Dim pfeature As IFeature = CType(pfeaturebuffer, IFeature)
        Dim nfeatcursor As IFeatureCursor = pfeatclass.Insert(True)

        Dim Xmin As Double
        Dim Ymin As Double
        Dim Xmax As Double
        Dim Ymax As Double

        If ToolStripTextBox10.Text = "Xmin" Then
            Dim player As ILayer = axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap.Layer(0)
            Xmin = player.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.XMin 'longitude of left bottom point
            Ymin = player.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.YMin 'latitude
            Xmax = player.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.XMax 'longitude of top right point
            Ymax = player.AreaOfInterest.Envelope.YMax 'latitude
        Else
            Xmin = Val(ToolStripTextBox10.Text)
            Ymin = Val(ToolStripTextBox11.Text)
            Xmax = Val(ToolStripTextBox12.Text)
            Ymax = Val(ToolStripTextBox13.Text)

        End If

        Dim numgridsLong As Integer = CType((Xmax - Xmin) / gInterval, Integer)
        Dim numgridsLat As Integer = CType((Ymax - Ymin) / gInterval, Integer)

        ReDim gridLong(numgridsLong, numgridsLat)
        ReDim gridLat(numgridsLong, numgridsLat)

        gridLong(0, 0) = Xmin
        gridLat(0, 0) = Ymin

        For j = 0 To (numgridsLat - 1)
            For i = 0 To (numgridsLong - 1)
                gridLong(i, j) = Xmin + i * gInterval
                gridLat(i, j) = Ymin + j * gInterval
                Dim pPolygon As IPolygon = getPolygon(gridLong(i, j), gridLat(i, j))
                'createPolygon(gridLong(i, j), gridLat(i, j), interval1, interval2)

                pfeature.Shape = pPolygon
                nfeatcursor.InsertFeature(pfeaturebuffer)
            Next i
        Next j

        nfeatcursor.Flush()
        pworkedit.StopEditOperation()
        pworkedit.StopEditing(True)

        'Adding lattitude and longitude field values to the mainName fileGDB
        AddLongLat()

        ' Adding a featureclass as a layer to Map Control
        Dim featWS As IFeatureWorkspace = retFWspace(PathName)
        Dim featclass As IFeatureClass = featWS.OpenFeatureClass(mainName)
        Dim gridFLayer As IFeatureLayer = New FeatureLayer
        With gridFLayer
            .FeatureClass = featclass
            .Name = mainName
            .Visible = True
        End With

        axMapControl1.AddLayer(gridFLayer)
        axMapControl1.ActiveView.FocusMap.RecalcFullExtent()

        disp_stat("GDB : " & PathName)
        disp_stat("Grid Interval: " & gInterval)
        disp_stat("Grids: " & numgridsLong & " * " & numgridsLat)
        Count = 0
        disp_stat("Feature count: " & FeatCount())

    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MakeGridTable()
    populategridtableAddcolumn()
    initialization()
    'AddColumn("Latitude")
    'AddColumn("Longitude")
    'AddColumn("Test")
    transfer("Latitude")
    transfer("Longitude")
    mruList.AddItem(mainPath) 'MRU List Loader
    disp_stat("Create GDB Executed")
    'save_log()

    watch.Stop()
    disp_stat(watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
```

Here I created a rectangle using four 3D points:

```vb
    Dim pPoint As IPoint = New PointClass()
    Dim pPointCollection As IPointCollection = New RingClass()
    Dim pGeomCollection As IGeometryCollection = New PolygonClass()
    pPoint.PutCoords(lat2, long2)
    pPoint.Z = Z2
    pPointCollection.AddPoint(pPoint)
    pPoint.PutCoords(lat1, long1)
    pPoint.Z = Z1
    pPointCollection.AddPoint(pPoint)

    pPoint.PutCoords(lat4, long4)
    pPoint.Z = Z4
    pPointCollection.AddPoint(pPoint)
    pPoint.PutCoords(lat3, long3)
    pPoint.Z = Z3
    pPointCollection.AddPoint(pPoint)
    pGeomCollection.AddGeometry(pPointCollection)
    Dim pOutGeometry As IGeometry = CType(pGeomCollection, IGeometry)
    Dim pZaware As IZAware = CType(pOutGeometry, IZAware)
    pZaware.ZAware = True
```

Now I created a 3D point to check if the distance calculation works fine

```vb
    Dim gpoint As IPoint = New PointClass()
    Dim gridgeometry As IGeometry = CType(gpoint, IGeometry)
    Dim gZaware As IZAware = CType(gridgeometry, IZAware)
    gZaware.ZAware = True
    gpoint.PutCoords(71.558, 21.663)
    gpoint.Z = 0
```

Here I gave Geographic coordinate systems to bothe polygon and point and projected them to UTM coordinate system as 3D operators works in projected systems rather than geographic coordinate systems

```vb
    Dim pSpatRefFact As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ISpatialReferenceFactory
    pSpatRefFact = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment

    Dim pGCS As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeographicCoordinateSystem
    pGCS = pSpatRefFact.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984)

    pOutGeometry.SpatialReference = pGCS
    gpoint.SpatialReference = pGCS

    'Now Define the Projected Coordinate System
    Dim projectedcosys As IProjectedCoordinateSystem
    projectedcosys = pSpatRefFact.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem(esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_WGS1984UTM_43N)

    'Now We need to project it
    pOutGeometry.Project(projectedcosys)        
    gridgeometry.Project(projectedcosys)
```

Now I use IProximity3D inerface to return the distance

```vb
    Dim pProxOp As IProximityOperator3D = CType(gpoint, IProximityOperator3D)
    Dim pReturnDistance As Double = pProxOp.ReturnDistance3D(pOutGeometry)
    MsgBox(pReturnDistance)
```

[image: Visual Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea but you seem to be constructing your rectangle from a ring and the help talks about wrapping rings in higher level geometry.

If it were me and as it looks like you are building a simple rectangle I would have built the polygon this way (not sure it makes a difference but worth a try?)...

```vb
Dim pPolygon As IPolygon4
Set pPolygon = New Polygon
Dim pZaware As IZAware
Set pZaware = pPolygon
pZaware.ZAware = True
Dim pPointColl As IPointCollection
Set pPointColl = pPolygon

Dim pPoint As IPoint
Set pPoint = New Point
Set pZaware = pPoint
pZaware.ZAware = True
pPoint.PutCoords 0, 0 ' dummy coordinates to show how to add them
pPoint.Z = 1

pPointColl.AddPoint pPoint

' repeat adding your points
```